# Passing a property to a slot

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to find the "cleanest" way of passing a property to a child component.

I have a custom component (lets call it `parent` in this example) that can take any child component via a `slot`. Imagine the parent component wants to update some property `x` of a child.

The solution that I've come up with uses scoped slots, like so:

```
// parent.vue

<template>
    … some template stuff
    <slot :x="parentX"></slot>
</template>

<script>
    ...component setup

    computed: {
        parentX: function() {
            return ...some number
        }
    },

    ...more component stuff
</script>
```

--

```
// child.vue

<template>
    ...some html that uses property x
</template>

<script>
    ...component setup

    props: { x: Number },

    ...more component stuff
</script>
```

--

```
// app.vue

<template>
    <parent>
        <template scope="A">
            <child :x="A.x" />
        </template>
    </parent>
</template>
```

This works, but it's not very nice for a couple of reasons:

1. The extra markup needed to wire then components together.
2. The fact that the user of these components needs to know about properties that they shouldn't need to know about. The parent component is sending an internal bit of state to it's child. The fact that I have to manually wire up this is a little annoying, especially because it's just boiler plate.

Is there a better way of doing this so I can say:

```
<template>
    <parent>
        <child />
    </parent>
</template>
```

Then all I need to know is that the child has a property `x`.

## UPDATE (28-10-18)

It's possible to remove some of the boiler-plate by using `slot-scope` directly on the child element. e.g.

```
<template>
    <parent>
        <child slot-scope="child" :x="child.x" />
    </parent>
</template>
```

but the real problem still persists. I need to manually wire up the components in the `app.vue` even though this has already been fully defined in the parent and child components.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: I want to solve this problem without use of the scoped slots too. So far I have dirty hack it call this.$parent.property in child component

Comment: I've improved things a little by removing the `<template>` tag and using `slot-scope` directly on the child component but the real problem still persists. I still have to manually wire the parent and child components together even though that has already been fully described in the parent component.

Comment: I read about vnode and vnode.componentOptions.propsData from this.$slots and I hope it may help.

Comment: This could be achieved with [render functions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), but I'm not sure if you want that extra layer of complexity.

Comment: It's unclear how the parent is supposed to know that the child takes a prop without the component user knowing that that is going on.

Comment: have you tried using `v-bind="child"`? this passes the object as a prop, so you don't need to do any definitions

Answer (score 0):

A slot is for uncoupled content. Your requirement is that the content be a component that takes a prop. It seems to me that what you want to do is pass the child component to the parent as a prop, and have the parent template do something like

```
<div :is="childComponent" :x="child.x"></div>
```